# How to SSR on specific routes on angular-universal?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, universal

I am using angular-universal in my `PWA` app for `SEO` purpose which is working fine, but it has the following issues

1). `PWA` app is not working in offline mode.
2). During first time load of the app, it flickers screen component (i think it is due to `SSR`)

So what I was thinking like if we are able to configure angular-universal like it will only process SSR on specific routes (i.e. product detail page) and rest of the routes will server as a normal angular app, so it will resolve screen flicker issue, also by default on root route it will work as normal angular app so `PWA` on offline mode will also work.

Is there any way to configure `SSR` on specific routes?

Here we can see that `SSR` is applying for every route:

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT});
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [503 ok (from serviceWorker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370912/503-ok-from-serviceworker)

Comment: you dont need to do that , your problem is related with [Content Security Policy (CSP)]
PWA offline feature is not enabled in your browser check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370912/503-ok-from-serviceworker/65465345#65465345) question wich is related with your problem.